# Django Export data from postGre to shapeFile

Tags: python, django, shapefile

I'm new in django and python.

I've tried to export database data to shapefile using https://bitbucket.org/springmeyer/django-shapes/src
 and i got a Segmentation fault. is there is anyway to make this work by only using django GeoDjango?

Answer (score 0):

That's a non-updated project. You can check this [a bit more up to date fork](https://github.com/sigma-geosistemas/django-shape-engine).

To check quickly if it works for you download the zip and copy the `shape-engine` folder inside your django project.

Install fiona (`pip install fiona`)

Add a new url to download the shapfile like

```
from .views import export
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [ url(r'^worldshapes/', export_worldshapes), ]
```

And a new view:

```
from shape_engine.shape_responder import ShpResponder
def export(request):
    from .models import WorldBorders
    w = WorldBorders.objects.all()
    shp_response = ShpResponder(w)
    shp_response.file_name = 'World Borders'
    return shp_response()
```

django-shape-engine only works in python 2.x. A couple of changes should be made to work with it in python 3. Basically, use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`